# Intellij Idea Live Template to create field and method at same time

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, live-templates

How to create field variable automatically when I create method used that field. I've create template like this:

```
void $METHOD_NAME$() {
    $FIELD_NAME$ = true;
}
```

when I type field name (e.g. `mState`) in method will create field as:

```
private boolean mState = false;
```

Hope someone help. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Can you give a real example of the desired code you want it to generate? (is it a getter/setter or something else?) Can you also share the configuration of your parameters? (a screenshot of the config would be best)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Sorry for late. I want something like this:

```
// this generated automatically
private boolean mBack = false;

// this from template
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mBack) super.onBackPressed();
    // other code
}
```

this is my config:
![image](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kvayqUX8Xgg/Wt3_eI5PgGI/AAAAAAAACiY/JwrJ5L0_Mi4ex2nebadHdtWaeW502U-KACLcBGAs/s1600/live_template.png).

Comment: Thats a huge template! I used to make larger templates when I just discovered the feature but I found that smaller templates are much easier in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the screenshot of your template, you can also create a field with the following live template:

```
private boolean $param$ = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if ($param$) super.onBackPressed();
  android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "$message$",
    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  $param$ = true;
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      $param$ = false;
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Where $param$ and $message$ are regular variables without anything special.

However, like I said in the comment on your question, I suggest to split it up in several smaller templates.
Consider to split it up in:
field + method with just:

```
private boolean $param$ = false;    

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if ($param$) super.onBackPressed();
  $param$ = true;
}
```

Then create a template for the message:

```
android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "$message$", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And last but not least, create a template for the postDelayed:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        $END$
    }
}, $delay$);
```

Note: the `$delay$` as a bonus you can even give it a default value or create a list of predefined values for ease of use.

Note2: Instead of `$param$ = false;` I've replaced it with `$END$`. This will position your cursor here once you've selected the delay. Now you can type mState = false manually here, or whatever code you need in the context at that moment. This makes the template much more flexible and easier to use.

PS. I suppose you want to call `super.onBackPressed()` only when the value is false (on the first invocation). In that case use `if (!$param$)` instead.

**// Update:**

In order to group the newly added field with the other fields and not halfway somewhere in your class between other methods, rearrange the code 
via the menu with: `Code -> rearrange code`.
To customise this, check your arrangement settings under: `settings -> code style -> <language> -> arrangement`

Comment: >Thats a huge template!
Oh I guess you're right, I was too passionate and had not thought of that.


but if I create a template like this:

<pre>
private boolean $param$ = false;    

// how I can keep other method position already written here

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if ($param$) super.onBackPressed();
  $param$ = true;
}
</pre>

Comment: Formatting is lost in comments, please update it in your original question instead. I suppose you want to group the fields and methods and don't have the field floating between other methods already written right? In that case, check the arrangement settings under the code style settings. Here you can group fields and methods etc. (invoke it with "rearrange code" action)